# How do interpolation fields in Ecto queries?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

The [Ecto documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html) shows how to do interpolation values. But I need dynamic fields in my queries. I have dozens of fields and write queries for each of them does not seem cohesive.

```
defmodule Hedone.SearchController do
  use Hedone.Web, :controller

  alias Hedone.User

  def idade(conn, %{"idade+" => maior, "idade-" => menor, "campo" => campo}) do
    IO.inspect campo
  query = from u in User, where: u.campo > ^maior and u.campo < ^menor, select: u.name
  pesquisa = Repo.all query
  IO.inspect pesquisa
  text conn, "Works"
end

end
```

This controller generates the following error:

```
** (Ecto.QueryError) web/controllers/search.ex:8: field `Hedone.User.campo` in `where` does not exist in the schema in query:

from u in Hedone.User,
  where: u.campo > ^18 and u.campo < ^40,
  select: u.name
```

*Automatically translated.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `campo` contains a string with the name of the field you want to use, e.g. `"age"`. You can use [`field`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#field/2) in the query for this:

```
def idade(conn, %{"idade+" => maior, "idade-" => menor, "campo" => campo}) do
  campo = String.to_existing_atom(campo)
  query = from u in User, where: field(u, ^campo) > ^maior and field(u, ^campo) < ^menor, select: u.name
  pesquisa = Repo.all query
  IO.inspect pesquisa
  text conn, "Works"
end
```

`field` expects the field to be an atom, so I've used `String.to_existing_atom` to safely convert a string to atom. Since you already must have defined the field in the schema of the model, `String.to_existing_atom` will not fail for any valid field name.

Comment: For _dozens of dynamic fields_ I would rather go with macros.

Comment: Sorry, I'm starting to program and look forward to putting my ideas online. I have not read the macro session. Why would it be better? So it works very well.

Comment: @mudasobwa how would you use macros here? could you expand a bit? I can't think of any reason to do that here but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Dogbert I have posted another [oversimplified] answer to demonstrate what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an example of another approach to the problem. One might use macros to handle this transformation since macros are being resolved in compile time:

```
defmacro idade(conn, formula, campo: binding) do
  q = formula |> String.replace "campo", binding
  quote do
    from u in User, where: unquote(q), select: u.name
      |> Repo.all
    text conn, "Works"
  end
end
```

and call it like:

```
idade(nil, "u.campo > ^maior and u.campo < ^menor", campo: "age")
```